# SEAndroid: Compile Error

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, seandroid

i got some SEAndroid problem, please see the following details :

Debug Command: adb shell logcat | findstr "denied:"

> 1. 07-06 22:51:41.569  3418  3418 I sh      : type=1400 audit(0.0:137):
>      avc: denied { read } for name="demolog-executor.sh" dev="mmcblk0p50" ino=867248
>      scontext=u:r:dumpstate:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
> 2. 07-06 22:51:41.569  3418  3418 I sh      : type=1400 audit(0.0:138): 
>      avc: denied { open } for path="/data/data/com.demo.LogTool/files/demolog-executor.sh" dev="mmcblk0p50" ino=867248 
>      scontext=u:r:dumpstate:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
> 3. 07-06 22:51:43.619  3489  3489 I sh      : type=1400 audit(0.0:209): 
>      avc: denied { read } for name="clear-logs.sh" dev="mmcblk0p50" ino=867237 
>      scontext=u:r:dumpstate:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
> 4. 07-06 22:51:43.619  3489  3489 I sh      : type=1400 audit(0.0:210): 
>      avc: denied { open } for path="/data/data/com.demo.LogTool/files/clear-logs.sh" dev="mmcblk0p50" ino=867237 
>      scontext=u:r:dumpstate:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=1

Then add a selinux rule in dumpstate.te:
 `allow dumpstate system_app_data_file:file {read open};`

But the compile gives me the error message like this:

> FAILED: out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy
>   /bin/bash -c "(out/host/linux-x86/bin/secilc -M true -G -c 30 out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/plat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/plat_sepolicy.cil out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/26.0.cil_intermediates/26.0.cil out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil -o out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy.tmp -f /dev/null ) && (out/host/linux-x86/bin/sepolicy-analyze out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy.tmp permissive > out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy.permissivedomains ) && (if [ \"userdebug\" = \"user\" -a -s out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy.permissivedomains ]; then             echo \"==========\" 1>&2;             echo \"ERROR: permissive domains not allowed in user builds\" 1>&2;             echo \"List of invalid domains:\" 1>&2;                 cat out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy.permissivedomains 1>&2;                exit 1;                 fi ) && (mv out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy.tmp out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy )"
>   neverallow check failed at out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil:3814
>     (neverallow base_typeattr_51_26_0 system_app_data_file_26_0 (file (create unlink open)))
>       
>       allow at out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil:7189
>         (allow dumpstate_26_0 system_app_data_file_26_0 (file (read open)))
>   neverallow check failed at out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/plat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/plat_sepolicy.cil:4389 from system/sepolicy/public/domain.te:874
>     (neverallow base_typeattr_51 system_app_data_file (file (create unlink open)))
>       
>       allow at out/target/product/msm8996/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil:7189
>         (allow dumpstate_26_0 system_app_data_file_26_0 (file (read open)))
>
> Failed to generate binary
>
> Failed to build policydb

Can somebody help me, please.